# Osmdroid - Map tile load issue

Tags: android, performance, load, tile, osmdroid

We are using the source code of osmdroid-android version 3.0.5 - Revision 970 . Also we are using the jars osmdroid-third-party-3.0.8.jar and osmdroid-packager-3.0.8.jar in our project for showing bing map. We are having tile load issue, where the map tile loads very slowly. We tried the fix given in the [link](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=289)  , with Revision r1073, but the map itself is not loading in this case. We are using Android 3.2 . Please let me know whether there is any other fix for this tile issue.

Comment: having same issue with 3.0.8.  Tried previous versions as well.  Did you find a fix?